# How to set logs for all request and response in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to add logs which maintain full details of requests and responses of every call in my project in laravel 5.4

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what exactly do you want to log? Where do you want to store these logs?

Comment: Hi Jerodev,Thank you for your response.I want a log which should contain all success and failed requests and responses like in codeiginter.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Laravel logging in your project and base on where you want to log , Laravel has different options such as Monolog and slack for cloud logging or daily log and single file log, read this doc for more Information, there is also for Laravel 5 or higher [Laravel Logging](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging)

Answer (score 0):

Recently i used a laravel package called [jeremykenedy/laravel-logger](https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-logger)
This is awesome library for logging activities, requests and response.